# Ocassionally reference throws Strict Error in php

Tags: php, reference

I have this code:

```
$config = & my__frame::get('config');
```

Sometimes it returns:

> PHP Strict Error: Only variables should be assigned by reference

and sometimes it don't.
What should I do in that case?

Comment: How do you implement the static method of the `get()`?

Comment: You'd better check why does that my__frame function return different stuff on each call.

Comment: get() returns object from registy if it exists or false if it don't

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `&` (ampersand) symbol, so that the instruction will look like this:

```
$config = my__frame::get('config');
```

Citing the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> As of PHP 5, the new operator returns a reference automatically, so assigning the result of new by reference results in an E_DEPRECATED message in PHP 5.3 and later, and an E_STRICT message in earlier versions.

Comment: but it operates on array:
get($name){
if(isset($options[$name]){
     return $options[$name];
 }
}
i want it to operate on the object, not on a copy

Comment: using `=&` could actually be valid if the `my__frame::get('config')` function is set to [return a reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)